# Can't edit the TFS buid definition through the VPN

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

I am an administrator on TFS. If I am in the office (connected to the domain directly) I can change the build definition easily, but when I use VPN it says "**Downloading Custom Assemblies**" and never finishes downloading. What is the problem with that? Does anybody encounter this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same machine? If not make sure you have upgraded VS 2013 to at least update 2, I've seen this problem with vanilla VS 2013 installations.

If it is the same machine you could try adding the URL for the TFS server to the trusted sites in your internet options.

If that doesn't work then it's probably a proxy server preventing the download of binary files. You need to speak to your network team and ask them for some help